# Parallel circuit Question

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

Re Question on why bulbs in battery powered parallel circuits get brighter when one or more are switched off or removed … understand the reasoning but why doesn’t this happen in a household light circuit?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the original question?  Without that there a lot of missing context.

Answer (score 2):

A real battery always has an [internal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance) (typically between $0.1\ \Omega$ and $0.3\ \Omega$).
Therefore, when you connect more light bulbs,
then the total current and hence the voltage
across the internal resistance of the battery will increase,
and the voltage across the bulbs will decrease.
[image]

On the other hand, your household power outlet has a very small internal resistance (very close to $0\ \Omega$).
Therefore the voltage across the light bulbs is independent of how many bulbs you have.
[image]

Comment: Many many many thanks Thomas ! 